# Quickest way to replicate small files on 4 machines?

Tags: rsync, scp

I have 4 servers, all on a secure local network.

Each server runs script.php (every minute).

script.php reads from a local dir called /arc, does a file test, and writes a new file back to /arc.

(These are small 2kb text files, being created at the rate of about 20 per second on each server).

I would like all 4 /arc dirs to be merged into one.

For example, when script.php runs on server1, I would like it to know about all the files in ALL the /arc dirs, not just the one on the local machine. And when server1 writes the file out into it's local /arc dir, servers2-4 must now see it in their /arc dirs.

Also of note, these files are perishable and all scoured every 10 minutes.

UPDATE: Currently, I am going to try NFS mounting all the dirs. The arc dirs are also tmpfs so it should be pretty fast.  Unless someone thinks there is a faster way, I am going to try this:

1) on each machine, I will NFS mount the /arc 
dirs to all the other machines. So 1 local and 3 NFS.

2) when script.php runs on any of the machines, there will be multiple "cp" commands to each of the arc dirs. this will ensure each machine always has the latest cached output.  (Is 20 copies per second X 4 locations over NFS a bottleneck? I hope not.)

3) since cached output is copied to all local machines, it means script.php never has to read a file over the NFS mount.  A local read of the arc cache takes 0.37 seconds. How long would it take to read the file over NFS? longer than that? That's what would happen if I copied to a single central location.

So, I'm trading multiple copy commands for reads.  But I THINK it's a good trade since the point is for script.php requests to run as fast as possible, which means minimizing time it takes to read a cached file.

Comment: If you want all four hosts to share the same data in the same directory, might it be better to turn /arc into an nfs shared by all four servers?

Comment: I agree and am exploring this option...but am worried about latency (script.php read time to NFS mount).  The whole purpose of these /arc files is that they act as cached output.  Script.php takes 2 seconds to run "new", but only 0.37 seconds when a cached file is available in /arc.  Therefore, if the NFS mount adds much more than .5 seconds or so, it's not even worth it.

Comment: 20 files per second, for 10 minutes is 12000 files, and then you are going to have the processed versions as well.  If you have all of those in one directory, then rewriting the directory node 20 times a second might well be a bottleneck, and would be a locking operation.  What file system you use matters here, as does the storage medium and the network latency.  It will help if you arrange the files into subdirectories so no single directory has more than a few hundred files in it.

Comment: If you are going with NFS, then just have your directory on one NFS server, and don't keep local copies.  The file system will do a certain amount of local caching anyway, though it will still need to check for changes on the server.

Answer (score 2):

rsync is designed for 1-way sync between 1 source and 1 destination. It is not suitable for reliable 2-way sync between 4 hosts.

A synchronization tool like SyncThing or BitTorrent Sync may work, although the rate of change of your files (20/second) may be too fast for those kind of tools.

My suggestion would be to designate one of the servers as the "master" (alternatively, setup a 5th machine or NAS) and network mount (eg, NFS) `/arc` from all the other machines to that master so the script on each machine is actually working in the same directory.

Another option if you can't accept the reliance on the single machine that is hosting the directory is to use something like DRBD to create a distributed block device that can replicate at the block level over the network.

Comment: Yeah I really agree with this answer. The sensible thing seems to be to dump all the files in a central location.

Comment: I have NFS mounted the arc dir on each machine, and this is all done in tmpfs.  Like I just mentioned above, the purpose of the arc dir is to hold cached output.  A new script.php request takes 2 seconds to execute but only 0.37 seconds to read a cached copy IF it resides on local machine.  So my big question is, how much lag is there potentially reading from an NFS mounted tmpfs dir across the local network, and would it be large enough to negate the benefits of the cached output?

Comment: @Corepuncher The network will be the bottleneck; so the exact impact depends on the performance and tuning of the network. The only way to get an accurate answer will be to test it.

Comment: I shall test it!

Comment: If it's taking you 0.37 seconds to read a cached local copy, you've probably got bigger problems than network latency.

Comment: 0.37 is the entire script up until the point it looks for cached copy.  I have to define several variables first in order to know what file to look for.

Answer (score 2):

Twenty 2k files per second... on 4 machines.  This sounds like what you really want is a database server.

MySQL, Postgres, SQLServer can all handle that update rate easily.

If each machine needs to copy to the other 3, then you need n-1 copies for each file.  So, 4 machines generating 20 files per second is 120 copies per second.  If you ever need a 5th machine the number doubles.  The 6th machine would double again.  You may not think you will grow in the future but you will.

If you were going to `scp` each file after it was created, that would be 3 `scp` commands each time script.php runs.  Considering how long scp takes to authenticate the session, that might take 1-2 seconds per run.  That's 60 `scp`s per second.

Instead you could just create the files and have another process that runs `rsync` in a loop.  Each time it runs rsync would pick up any new files.  The time between file creation and when it makes it to the other servers would be seconds or minutes.  That is ok if you want to do backups of the data and can withstand some data loss in the event of an unplanned outage.  It isn't sufficient if you want the other servers to have the information instantly.

On the other hand, if you use a database, all 3 machines would have cached connections to the database and the updates would be very very quick.  The data would be available instantly.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I would be using a simple cp command since all these machines will remain on local network.  Does that change your view? Also, the purpose of these files in /arc dir are to act as cached output that script.php can read.  Script.php takes 2 seconds to run a "new" request, but only 0.37 seconds of it can read from the cache.  Also note I am working from tmpfs to tmpfs between machines.

Comment: If you are going to use NFS and "cp" instead, that could work. You have have a different set of problems (if any 1 machine fails, the other 3 will hang waiting for their NFS server to come back to life).  You now have a very different question and should consider changing the title of this question to "How can I replicate small files between 4 machines?"

Answer (score 1):

If you have good control over your servers, then I think building around a messaging server like RabbitMQ could be the way to go.  Rather than creating files, you put messages into a queue, and your script subscribes to those queue events, does processing, and then puts results back on the queue to be picked up by the other servers.

I don't think rsync is the way to go.  `lsync`'s model might be interesting in that it watches kernel events for changes, but it's a master/slave arrangement, and I'm not sure it'd work for your situation.

You might do better with a shared network file system of some sort, as @Andy suggests. (NFS, GFS, Gluster) come to mind, and there are many more.  Be careful of locking issues though, and about what happens if connection to a file server is interrupted.

@TomOnTime's response is probably correct in that he says that a file based system is probably the wrong choice.  The main merit of a SQL based solution is that you probably already have the DB server set up.  There are more traps than you might imagine though in making this sort of thing efficient in SQL.

EDIT:

If as you say this is a caching system, you might also want to look at memcached, redis, or even varnish.

Do your applications know in advance what they expect to be in the cache without having to ask for a list?

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. The idea is for these small files inside /arc to act as cached copies.  They are very perishable...only valid for about 5 - 10 minutes before they are removed.  When a client hits script.php, it returns in about 2 seconds.  A cached response (currently on same machine) takes 0.37 seconds.  So whatever way I choose to sync the machines, speed is the most important issue.  It's a local network so simple cp commands over NFS are ok.  Also these /arc dirs and files all reside in tmpfs.